# the browser back button won't work

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, google-chrome, browser

I'm working on a Java webapplication. Something I did, perhaps the javascript, caused the back button of the browser to stop working (it actually just shows a thinking circle on the tab in chrome).

**The problem seems to be only in chrome**

I'm not sure exactly what to look for...

What can cause the browser back button not to work?

Comment: Does the problem just appear in Chrome, or on any browser?

Comment: Can you post some code and/or an example of it?

Comment: Yelling at the PC usually works.

Comment: Does it only happen in your application or all around? Only chrome? I'm currently experiencing this problem in version 14.0.835.8 dev-m. I suspect this may not have anything to do with your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open bug on Chrome. It may not have anything to do with your application: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1893e974f696f250&hl=en

**Edit:**

[Here's the quick link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91000) to the actual reported bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `location.replace` method anywhere? If you're talking in general and not just in Chrome, it's the only thing I can think of that would cause the back button not to work.

See the first point [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Disable-Back-button-m446.aspx).

Other than that, and especially if it just happens on Chrome, a browser bug seems much more likely.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a server side problem. Make sure you don't have any infinite loops and limit the runtime of your script.